# Безопасная передача пароля в asp.net core 6.0 через переменную среды

Tags: c#, asp.net, core

appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "MailSettings": {
    "SmtpLogin": "user@user.com",
    "Password": "",
    "Host": "smtp.server.com",
    "Port": 465
  }
}
```

MailSettings.cs:

```
public class MailSettings
    {
        public string SmtpLogin { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Host { get; set; }
        public int Port { get; set; }
    }
```

program.cs:

```
IConfigurationSection conf = builder.Configuration.GetSection("MailSettings");

builder.Services.Configure<MailSettings>(conf);
```

MailController.cs:

```
public class MailController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IOptions<MailSettings> demoOptions;

    public MailController(IOptions<MailSettings> demoOptions)
        {

            this.demoOptions = demoOptions;
        }
}
```

в переменных среды есть переменная:

PASS=1234

При запуске приложения, строка

```
builder.Services.Configure<MailSettings>(conf);
```

передает в контроллер заполненный объект MailSettings, данные для которого берутся из appsettings.json, где поле Password пустое.  Это хорошо, но я хочу до передачи данных в контроллер полю  MailSettings.Password присвоить значение переменной среды PASS, чтобы контроллер получил объект demoOptions.Password == 1234

Кто знает как это сделать? Как заменить значение поля Password="" из appsettings.json значением переменной среды?

Comment: `string password = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PASS") ?? string.Empty;`

Comment: aepot, вопрос немного не об этом. Как получить значение переменной среды понятно. Непонятно вот что: команда builder.Services.Configure<MailSettings>(conf) создает экземпляр MailSettings, устанавливает его свойства значениями из полей appsettings.json и передает в контроллер. В appsettings.json поле Password пустая строка (по понятным причинам безопасности). Нужно чтобы вместо пустой строки перед передачей в контроллер подставлялось значение переменной среды PASS, то бишь тот самый Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PASS"). Возможно я туманно мыслю...

Comment: [`config.AddEnvironmentVariables();`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#cp) ?